# Solr loads entire index into memory

Tags: java, solr, indexing

I am using solr for data similar to 
name:age:sex:balance:nextbalance:interest

I have 30 M records totaling to 4G on disk. I am retrieving by age:23 which is only 50 records. I have indexed="true" in the schema xml. Solr seems to load the entire index on disk into memory (4G). Isnt it supposed to retrieve only the 40 odd records into memory ?

Comment: <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>
I am running OutOfMemory when trying to search with age:23. It loads the entire index into memory.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is document cache. You need to specify the size of it. Can you please check the following in solrconfig.xml?

```
<!-- documentCache caches Lucene Document objects (the stored fields for each document).
  -->
<documentCache
  class="solr.LRUCache"
  size="16384"
  initialSize="16384"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on how you configure the cache (what it does and doesn't keep in memory). Loading the entire index into memory can give you huge performance boosts in terms of the time needed to retrieve results, regardless of the query.

Details on configuring cache, and details on performance factors:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/SolrPerformanceFactors

Answer (score 1):

Fields that are stored but not indexed, are saved on disk but not in RAM. However, 100% of the records are indeed indexed in RAM and those indexes contain all of the indexed fields. But inverted indexes are rather efficient for that.

However, when you do queries then SOLR does retrieve the entire set of stored (but not indexed) field contents into RAM for the records which match. This is usually considered to be desirable caching behavior because it means that search results can be transmitted sooner which reduces the overall query turnaround time. As usual with SOLR, you can configure caching behavior in many ways to match your RAM budget and database needs. Have a look at the possibilities in solrconfig.xml.

Note that this is a complex area and you probably will find it difficult to fully understand caching if Google is your main info source. This is an area where it is better to learn from one of the books on SOLR.

Comment: What would be a good book to learn on performance tuning of SOLR?

Comment: Any book is better than no book at all. SOLR is so easy to set up that many people don't take the time to do some research and learn how to use all the buttons and knobs that it offers. So if you read any book and apply what you learn, you will be way ahead of the crowd which relies too much on default settings and a couple of recipes from the blogosphere.

Comment: I actually followed your advice, BEFORE. I am right now finished with the SOLR cookbook, But right now I am looking for something more didactic (I love cookbooks, but they are good for later). My experience shows recommendations from peers, is better then none.