# Load entire Solr Instance in memory

Tags: windows, tomcat, solr

I am trying to load entire Solr instance in memory, I have 60 million records with 10 fields, *(6 fields are indexed which icnlude `DateTime`, `c_Text` and `string`)*. My total solr instance size on disk is 15 GB, I have set the JVM Memory to:

```
Initial Memory Pool: 2048  (2 GB)
Maximum Memory Pool: 20480 (20 GB)
```

I changed the cache configuration in `solrconfig.xml` as:

```
<documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
               size="6000000"
               initialSize="2000000"
               autowarmCount="0"/>
```

But still for each search it reads from the disk (checked through PerfMon utility on windows). Also in Task Manager it shows `tomcat` taking 500 MB of RAM. I have seen this question: [Solr loads entire index into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704349/solr-loads-entire-index-into-memory) but it doesn't have an accepted answer and I also tried increase the cache size according to that question but still it doesn't increase the memory usage for `tomcat`.

I am using Solr 4.4 with Tomcat 7.0.42

Comment: You should probably reduce the size of the cache and the max memory for Tomcat. Let the OS take care of caching the index files. Initially, Solr will need to go to the disk for each search but over time the entire index will get cached by the OS (assuming that you have enough free RAM).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RAMDirectory` to build the whole index into RAM.

This can be done in your solrconfig.xml

```xml
<config>

    <!-- ... -->

    <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" 
        class="org.apache.solr.core.RAMDirectoryFactory"/> 

    <!-- ... -->

</config>
```

However with everything in live, this comes with Pros and Cons. A good elaboration can be read in the SO question [Need to know pros and cons of using RAMDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582377/need-to-know-pros-and-cons-of-using-ramdirectory).

You should then consider to decrease the size of your cache.